How to Deploy a MonoRepo with a NextJS and a Node Js Sever to any free cloud hosting platform?
The Structure of my Monorepo is attached in the image. This is a Turbo mono repo , where the web has a NextJS frontend and the server directory has a Node Js Server.enter image description hereenter image description here
Tried finding vids and tutorials , few of them were of vercel but then it only had frontend
